# How to detect if i am on plugin's settings page

Tags: plugins, options

Let's say, in admin, i use `add_menu_page`...

Is there any function, which determines, if current admin screen is the settings page of that `menu_age` ?

i.e.

```
if($current_screen == "my_plugins_settings_page") 
....
```

or how can i detect whether the page you are viewing in dashboard, is that plugin settings page?

(p.s. I dont need rought solution like:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUESR_URI'] == '/wp-admin/admin.php?page=xyz-slug')
```

Comment: look the result of `get_current_screen()` to know on which page you are.

Comment: @mmm thanks, i used that, with `stripos` to check if the slug is inside the `get_current_screen()`...